# Set returns value but Get returns null

Tags: java

I am trying to save a file path selected by the user by using Set & Get, When the user clicks save in a file chooser the path is returned to my set method - This is shown using a `System.out.println`. But when I try to use get the value returns `null`. Why is this?

My action listener class:

```
public class Action implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        GetSet get = new GetSet();

        if(e.getSource().equals(saveProject)){

            try {
                CreateProject op = new CreateProject();
                loadProjectUrl = op.setProjectUrl();                    
                get.setLoadProjectUrl((String)loadProjectUrl);

                File file = new File(loadProjectUrl);

                //Create the file
                if (file.createNewFile()){
                    System.out.println("File is created!");

                }else{
                    System.out.println("File already exists.");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoubleViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        };

        if(e.getSource().equals(ruler)){
            System.out.println("ruler button clicked");
            String a = get.getLoadProjectUrl();
            System.out.println(a);
        };
    }
}
```

My getSet Class:

```
public class GetSet {

    String loadProjectUrl;

    public String getLoadProjectUrl(){

        return loadProjectUrl;

    }

    public void setLoadProjectUrl(String loadProjectUrl){

        this.loadProjectUrl = loadProjectUrl;
        System.out.println("set url = "+ loadProjectUrl);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a ***NEW*** GetSet object each time the listener is called, and so even though you're changing the state of one, this will have no effect on the next instance. Create ***ONE*** of these objects, not within the listener's call back method (the `actionPerformed(...)` method) but rather as a field of the class, and change its state.

e.g., change this:

```
public class Action implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        GetSet get = new GetSet();
        if(e.getSource().equals(saveProject)){
            try {
                CreateProject op = new CreateProject();
                loadProjectUrl = op.setProjectUrl();                    
                get.setLoadProjectUrl((String)loadProjectUrl);

                // ....
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoubleViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        };

        if(e.getSource().equals(ruler)){
            System.out.println("ruler button clicked");
            String a = get.getLoadProjectUrl();
            System.out.println(a);
        };
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public class Action implements ActionListener{
    private GetSet get = new GetSet();  // **** added

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // GetSet get = new GetSet();
        if(e.getSource().equals(saveProject)){
            try {
                CreateProject op = new CreateProject();
                loadProjectUrl = op.setProjectUrl();                    
                get.setLoadProjectUrl((String)loadProjectUrl);

                // ....
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoubleViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        };

        if(e.getSource().equals(ruler)){
            System.out.println("ruler button clicked");
            String a = get.getLoadProjectUrl();
            System.out.println(a);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers I new it must've been a simple mistake somewhere! Been trying to figure this out for ages!